# Rendering system controls fonts outside the class

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, fonts, cleartype

for quite some time now I'm trying to find a solution to the "per-apllication cleartype fonts" problem.

I want to implement cleartype fonts for a `TextBox` or a `Button` or a `ComboBox` or any other non-custom/stock control.

well, there is one simple way to achive this that I know of, and that is, overriding the OnPaint method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    pevent.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

    base.OnPaint(pevent);
}
```

and this works just fine but the thing is that I want to do this without inheriting any of this controls and somehow change the font properties from outside the class.

the method that I've used so far without to much success was to install a 'Hook Procedure' and listen for the messages sent to the controls. the code bellow is part of the `Form1 class`:

```
// the delegate with the same signature as the callback function
private delegate int HookMessages(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

// when the Load event of the Form takes place the controls are created
// and the method that sets the hooks is called
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Name = "btn";
    btn.Parent = this;
    btn.Size = new Size(this.ClientRectangle.Width - 10, 20);
    btn.Location = new Point(5, tbx.Top + tbx.Height + 10);
    btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 1, 1, 1);
    btn.Text = "Click ME";

    HookControlMessages();
}

// the hook that monitors control's events is set for the current thread
private void HookControlMessages()
{
    if (hookWndHandle == 0)
    {
        HookWndProcedure = new HookMessages(HookWndProcMessages);

        hookWndHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
            WindowHookTypes.WH_CALLWNDPROC,
            HookWndProcedure,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (int)GetCurrentThreadId());

        if (hookWndHandle == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Window`s messages hooking failed.");

            return;
        }
    }
}

// the callback function
private static int HookWndProcMessages(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    int nextHook = 0;

    try
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            CWPSTRUCT m = (CWPSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CWPSTRUCT));

            _thisInstance.CheckWndProcMsgs(m);
        }

        nextHook = CallNextHookEx(hookWndHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    catch
    {
        nextHook = 0;
    }

    return nextHook;
}

private void CheckWndProcMsgs(CWPSTRUCT m)
{
    if (m.hwnd == ((this.Controls.Find("btn", true) as Control[])[0] as Button).Handle)
    {
        #region BUTTON

        switch (m.message)
        {
            case (int)WindowsMessages.WM_CREATE:
                {
                    // when the handle of the control is created also a new font is created
                    // and a WM_SETFONT message sent along with the specification that a redraw must be performed
                    Rect rc = new Rect(new Rectangle(0, 0, ((this.Controls.Find("btn", true) as Control[])[0] as UButton).Width, ((this.Controls.Find("btn", true) as Control[])[0] as UButton).Height));
                    hFontNew = CreateFont(
                        25, 5, 2, 0, 900, 0, 0, 0,
                        (byte)FontCharSet.OEM_CHARSET,
                        (byte)FontPrecision.OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                        (byte)FontClipPrecision.CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                        (byte)FontQuality.DEFAULT_QUALITY,
                        (byte)(FontPitchAndFamily.DEFAULT_PITCH | FontPitchAndFamily.FF_DONTCARE),
                        "Verdana");

                    SendMessage(m.hwnd, (uint)WindowsMessages.WM_SETFONT, hFontNew, (IntPtr)1);
                }
                break;
            case (int)WindowsMessages.WM_SETFONT:
                {
                    // the purpose of this block is to verify if the new font is set correct
                    LOGFONT lf = new LOGFONT();
                    IntPtr lf0 = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(lf));

                    GetObject((IntPtr)m.wparam, Marshal.SizeOf(lf), lf0);
                    lf = (LOGFONT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lf0, lf.GetType());

                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lf0);
                }
                break;
            case (int)WindowsMessages.WM_DESTROY:
                {
                    // when the control is destroyed the new font is also deleted
                    if (hFontNew != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        DeleteObject(hFontNew);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

this piece will work perfectly for a window created with CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx functions or if the `Paint event` will be handled by the user for a custom paint, but what I wish is to leave all the painting to the system and only change the font without any other interventions to the control.

should this approach work ? if not, could someone explain me why ? I know that when system paints the controls it uses the font that is set by the `Control.Font` property of the class but, shouldn't it also use the font rendering from the window messages ?
when the class handles system messages in the `WndProc` method, doesn't it relay on the data that came in the `Message.WParam & Message.LParam` of `WndProc` while painting ?

eg. when painting the text, shouldn't the system use WM_GETFONT to use the apropriate font ?
I for one don't know of any Control property that sets the font rendering outside the class.

are there any other solutions for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I see it's starting to become a habit answering my own questions :D

well .. no problem as long as I find an answer,

anyhow, the solution to my question is quite simple:
to render a button, or a label, or a groupbox text outside the class (without subclassing the base class and overrinding the OnPaint method) one should set the control's `FaltStyle` property to system (eg. `myControl.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;`), so the system will handle the drawing.

then, install a global window procedure and override the `WM_PAINT` message. here is one good place I've found to create a new logical font and send the WM_SETFONT message to the control.

works nicely, but, there is a simpler way !

I've also played around with `Font.FromLogFont(LOGFONT)` for a bit but without any success;
the font quality it's not set and yet, I don't know any reason why not.

if someone could explain why, please do so.